# Three monitors connected to AMD 7970, only HDMI works

Tags: drivers, ati, multiple-monitors, 13.04, hdmi

Just made a clean install of Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit on my desktop machine with an AMD 7970 graphics card installed. I use a 24" Samsung screen that is connected via DVI as my primary monitor, a 19" Fujitsu Siemens screen as my secondary monitor connected via DVI -> VGA, and last I've got my 32" television connected via HDMI. I've installed the latest AMD Catalyst 13.4 drivers for the GPU, but no matter how I configure my monitor setup in AMDCCC, it will only let me use the television that is connected via HDMI?

If I disconnect the television it will let me arrange my desktop as I want it, with my 24" Samsung screen as my primary screen to the right, and with the 19" Fujitsu monitor to left. But as soon I connect the television, it will only show the picture on that screen.

I just need the workspace on my primary and secondary screen on my Ubuntu partition, as I only use the telly for gaming on Windows.

Are there any way that I can have all three monitors connected at the same time, but only use my primary and secondary screen?

I hope you guys understand my problems, sorry for my bad english :)